# MFMailComposer and dismissing the view

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a view that uses the `MFMailCompseViewController` and it works great! However, when I send the email or cancel the email, the view dismisses like it should, but when it returns to the previous view, it is scrolled down past the content on the view. When you scroll up, the rest of the content is cut off. How do I dismiss the `MFMailComposeViewController` and show the previous view correctly? I have included some images to help explain.

[image: Image 1][image: Image 2][image: Image 3][image: Image 4]

Comment: Are you presenting the view in a Modal View Controller?

Comment: try to add [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRect animated:YES];in viewWillAppear.

Comment: @Matt No it isnt in a Modal View Controller. At least I dont think it is? The MFMailComposeViewController is from the Message framework so I dont know.

Comment: @Madhusudhan That code gives me a few errors. Unexpected type name 1CGRect1: expected expression

Comment: [yourScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480) animated:YES];dont forget to add delegate to scrollView.

Comment: what is the contentSize of your scrollview.